# How to retain a variable after starting another activity

Tags: java, android, static

When I try to access a list tournaments,  which has been initialized in the following class:

```
public class AdminControl extends AppCompatActivity {

    Firebase ref;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    public static List <Tournament> tournaments;
    ListView list;
    Tournament [] temp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_control);
        Toolbar b = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        b.setTitle("Tournaments");
        setSupportActionBar(b);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createNewTournament(v);
            }
        });
        AdminLogin.firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tournaments = (ArrayList) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Object [] objArr = tournaments.toArray();
                temp = new Tournament[objArr.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++){
                    temp[i] = (Tournament) objArr[i];
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        if (tournaments == null){
            tournaments = new ArrayList<Tournament>();
        }
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<Tournament> tempAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tournament>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);
        list.setAdapter(tempAdapter);
    }

    public void createNewTournament(View v) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, TournamentCreator.class);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

After I leave that task and instantiate a new activity, `TournamentCreator` by calling the `createNewTournament` method right above, I try to access the `static` list tournaments from the `TournamentCreator` activity. However, it is displayed as `null` (`Object a`). I thought that static variables would always remain constant. Is there some sort of problem in what I am doing?

Tournament Creator class

```
public class TournamentCreator extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Object a = AdminControl.tournaments;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tournament_creator);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                beginTournament(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void beginTournament(View v) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Tournament newTourn = new Tournament(text.getText().toString());
        AdminControl.tournaments.add(newTourn);
        Firebase userRef = AdminLogin.firebase.child("users").child(AdminLogin.firebase.getAuth().getUid());
        userRef.setValue(AdminControl.tournaments);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: May be it is better to use another singleton class to manage the tournament list. It is better not to mix your views (activity) and model (tournament) classes since view classes like activities and fragments in Android undergo several life cycle events such as onCreate() etc

Comment: Can't you just use the `onActivityResult()` to return the created tournament?

Comment: I don't have the perfect answer, but I can say there is nothing wrong with referencing a static variable from another activity.  If there was a problem accessing it, you would get some other error, but for whatever reason, the variable really is null.  So... you could try putting  "   Log.i(TAG,"value of tournaments is " + tournaments.toString());   "   inside your createNewTournament method, to see what is actually in that variable right before you launch the new activity... and then troubleshoot backwards from there.

Comment: To build on what @BooberBunz said, if you were to set some hardcoded values for you `List`, you would be able to access them in a different activity. Try that to make sure nothing is setting your list to `null` unexpectedly, if that works then you need to figure out why `onDataChange` is not working properly.

Comment: It looks like tournaments was being set to null :)